# program displaying to few digits

Tags: python, digits

This program computes the square root of 2, but it will not display the digits to my desired accuracy of 1000 digits, but instead it only displays 50 digits.

here is the program

```
import math 
a=format(2.0**0.5, '.1000')   
print a
```

I would like to know how to write a program to display more digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 100
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573')
>>> getcontext().prec = 1000
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621070388503875343276415727350138462309122970249248360558507372126
441214970999358314132226659275055927557999505011527820605714701095599716059702745345968620147285174186408891986095523292304843087143214508397626036279
952514079896872533965463318088296406206152583523950547457502877599617298355752203375318570113543746034084988471603868999706990048150305440277903164542
478230684929369186215805784631115966687130130156185689872372352885092648612494977154218334204285686060146824720771435854874155657069677653720226485447
015858801620758474922657226002085584466521458398893944370926591800311388246468157082630100594858704003186480342194897278290641045072636881313739855256
117322040245091227700226941127573627280495738108967504018369868368450725799364729060762996941380475654823728997180326802474420629269124859052181004459
84215059112024944134172853147810580360337107730918286931471017111168391658172688941975871658215212822951848847')
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at mpmath

import mpmath

mpmath.mp.dps = 1000

print mpmath.sqrt(2.0)

1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621070388503875343276415727350138462309122970249248360558507372126441214970999358314132226659275055927557999505011527820
605714701095599716059702745345968620147285174186408891986095523292304843087143214508397626036279952514079896872533965463318088296406206152583523950547457502877599617298355752203375318570113543746
034084988471603868999706990048150305440277903164542478230684929369186215805784631115966687130130156185689872372352885092648612494977154218334204285686060146824720771435854874155657069677653720226
485447015858801620758474922657226002085584466521458398893944370926591800311388246468157082630100594858704003186480342194897278290641045072636881313739855256117322040245091227700226941127573627280
495738108967504018369868368450725799364729060762996941380475654823728997180326802474420629269124859052181004459842150591120249441341728531478105803603371077309182869314710171111683916581726889419
75871658215212822951848847