# Why Decimal(2**0.5) doesn't give the number in the predefined accuracy?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing the following inspired by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247776/program-displaying-to-few-digits):

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> import math
>>> getcontext().prec = 1000
>>> Decimal(2**0.5)
Decimal('1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125')
>>> Decimal(math.sqrt(2))
Decimal('1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125')
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641572735013846230912297024924836055850737212644121497099935831413222665927505592755799950501152782060571470109559971605970274534596862014728517418640889198609552329230484308714321450839762603627995251407989687253396546331808829640620615258352395054745750287759961729835575220337531857011354374603408498847160386899970699004815030544027790316454247823068492936918621580578463111596668713013015618568987237235288509264861249497715421833420428568606014682472077143585487415565706967765372022648544701585880162075847492265722600208558446652145839889394437092659180031138824646815708263010059485870400318648034219489727829064104507263688131373985525611732204024509122770022694112757362728049573810896750401836986836845072579936472906076299694138047565482372899718032680247442062926912485905218100445984215059112024944134172853147810580360337107730918286931471017111168391658172688941975871658215212822951848847')
>>> 2**0.5
1.4142135623730951
```

**Why `Decimal(2**0.5)` isn't 1000 digits long?**

Comment: Because `2**0.5` isn't 1000 digits long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `2 ** 0.5` is being calculated as a `float` and then converted to a `Decimal`. Instead, use two `Decimal`s from the start:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec = 100
>>> Decimal(2) ** Decimal('0.5')
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573')
```

It's important that you use `'0.5'` rather than `0.5` so that `Decimal` interprets `0.5` on its own without any intermediate loss of precision from `0.5` being converted to a `float` and then to a `Decimal`. (As `0.5` is `2 ** -1`, there might not be any loss of precision, but it's better to be safe than sorry.)

Comment: You aren't allowed to have a `Decimal` to the power of a `float` anyway

Comment: @jamylak: Right, but I was cautioning against `Decimal(2) ** Decimal(0.5)`, not `Decimal(2) ** 0.5`.

Comment: I just thought of that, but then again you should be writing all your decimals with strings to be consistent IMHO

Comment: @jamylak: Yeah, maybe. I write all non-integral ones in strings, but I know that Python won't mess with my integers, so I don't quote them.